# Jobs in sites other than stack overflow

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, jobs

I am new to stack exchange. What I figured out is that there are no job sections in sites other than stack overflow. Is my observation correct? And if yes, is there no scope of getting a job through these sites?

I would request the site team to have some job scope for the other fields too!

Answer (score 6):

Creating a successful two-sided market (with both employers and job-seekers) takes a fairly large site to make it work. Our main site is Stack Overflow (for developers) which has our largest audience by far, so that is where our current careers-related products are focused. There has been some interest in perhaps expanding the listings to include more of our IT-related sites, but I don't know if or when that might happen. But if there is ever a time when we can expand out even further to our *smaller* sites, it would likely have to be part of a more comprehensive development effort. I'm not privy a timeline where that might be considered, but it is not part of our *immediate* plans at this time.